# C++ on MacOS: show date and time issue

Tags: c++, macos, c++14, clang++

I bought a MacBook Pro and I've been using MacOS for the past two days. I've been trying to write this C++ code that outputs the date and time using `chrono` and `ctime` libraries. 
This code was working just fine on my Windows machine and my CentOS7 server. However, on my MacBook Pro it fails to compile.
This is the error message I get when I try to compile with G++:

```
main.cpp:19:61: error: no viable conversion from 'time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock,
      duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000000>>>' to 'const
      time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, duration<[...], ratio<[...], 1000000>>>'
    std::time_t date = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
                                                            ^~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1340:28: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long,
      std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >' to 'const
      std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long,
      std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000> > > &' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS time_point
                           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1340:28: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long,
      std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >' to 'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock,
      std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000> > > &&' for 1st argument
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1359:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'std::__1::chrono::system_clock' against 'std::__1::chrono::steady_clock'
    time_point(const time_point<clock, _Duration2>& t,
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/chrono:1566:53: note: passing argument to
      parameter '__t' here
    static time_t     to_time_t  (const time_point& __t) _NOEXCEPT;
                                                    ^
1 error generated.
basavyr@Roberts-MacBook-Pro simpleTest %
```

Here is the code:

```
void getTime()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::time_t date = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::cout << std::ctime(&date);
}
int main()
{
getTime();
}
```

I assume the issue has to do with the fact that MacOS is using CLANG compiler?
Any ideas how can I solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is only likely to work when `std::high_resolution_clock` is the same type as `std::system_clock`. There is no guarantee that time points from different clocks are the same or convertible.

For conversion to `time_t` which only has seconds resolution `system_clock` will be perfectly adequate:

```
void getTime()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::time_t date = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    std::cout << std::ctime(&date);
}
int main()
{
    getTime();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense now. Thank you!